# Error 1053: "The service did not respond in a timely fashion"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make  windows service in python. 
I have three source files: add_to_startup.py (adding my service to windows startup), run_as_a_service.py (runs my program as a service) and test.py (my program).

First i create .exe with pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller -F --onefile --hidden-import=win32timezone run_as_a_service.py test.py add_to_startup.py
```

When i trying to start service error occurs:

```
Error 1053: The service did not respond in a timely fashion.
```

If i delete strings with test import and test.service() function, service works.

run_as_service.py:

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
import sys
import time
import test

class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "test"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test"
    _svc_description_ = "test test"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.isAlive = False
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.isAlive = True
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                                servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                                (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        while self.isAlive:
            test.service()
            time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(AppServerSvc)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

test.py:

```
import add_to_startup

def service():
    print("Hello world")
```

Comment: There's a number of similar questions already, maybe you can find a solution there https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+service+error+1053

Comment: I  saw these questions. Unfortunately those answers are not solving my problem. All necessary variables are written in PATH. The libraries are in the right folders

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar problem and I have tried everything I can find